# Windows Service need to monitor error logging? Ideas?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

I have a windows service that runs 24/7 on one of our servers.

It connects to an external company as of late that company has been going down a lot.

I need to set something up that will essentially monitor when we have had 25 errors in the last minute within the error logs for this service.

I am guessing that I will have to create a table and insert these errors into the table as they are being logged and then set up something that checks via a tsql query whether or not 25 have occurred in the last minute? (then send out an email or update a dashboard monitoring page for support)

Really my question is does anyone have a better idea than this?  Someone must have done something better than this in the past.  I guess I have never attempted to read straight from logs.  Maybe that would be a better route.

Any ideas direction are greatly appreciated on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft System Center Operations Manager does things like this.

Comment: The price says "Call a Local Sales Representative", so it miiiight be overkill for this particular issue.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/buy/pricing-licensing.aspx

Comment: If you just want to know when the external company's site is down, you could use something like [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com) or [monitor.us](http://www.monitor.us) to alert you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging is fun. :/

Your options are essentially:

1. Log to a database server - Advantage: easy to read from other locations.  Disadvantage: you need a database server.  If the project doesn't already include one, might be a pain.  Also, logging fails if problem is in network connectivity.
2. Log to the Event Log - Advantage: fast to write locally.  Can be read remotely.. with the correct user permissions.  Disadvantage: You'll be querying this a lot and the event log isn't exactly built for that.
3. Log to a file - Advantage: extremely fast write.  Disadvantage: Requires a lot of permission setup for remote code to access.  May be corrupted/lost/deleted etc.
4. Use additional software such as System Center Operations Manager.  Advantage: this is exactly the type of thing that was built for.  Disadvantage: cost/setup.

---

Those are in my order of preference.

Comment: 1. does not work when you want to log that you can't connect to a database server.  Also, for high-volumes, logging to a database server is way too slow.

Comment: If you do want to use a database I have used ms enterprise library (entlib), msmq + sql server.  It really is fairly easy to set up, can handle large loads, you can put the db anywhere and even if one or both machines are down it will handle it gracefully and send the logs when both machines are able to connect again.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with an external web API that my Windows Service calls periodically.

My solution was to just use NLog to write errors to a text log file, and keep a counter in the service itself of the number of failures without a success.  If the counter exceeds a configurable threshold, I write a Critical entry to NLog rather than an Error entry, and configure NLog to email an alias that several folks on the operations team get when there is a Critical event.

If you need to strictly implement the "25 errors in the last minute" semantic, you could write errors to an in-memory constrained (to a max of 25 items) queue.  If the queue length gets to 25, check if the first item in the queue is within the last minute.  If so, write a Critical error to the log.